# Overloading >> operator for an fstream object reads the object twice

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, fstream

I am trying to make a program that reads from a `student.txt` file, and takes the information from that file and places it in a vector of students.

Student.txt:

```
1 James 23
0 HaHa 7012
1 Jay-Z music
```

I overloaded the `>>` operator:

```cpp
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& input, Student& student)
{
    char id;
    std::string user, pswd;
    input >> id >> user >> pswd;

    if (id == '0')
    {
        student.setUsername(user);
        student.setPassword(pswd);
    }
    return input;
}
```

For the `student` class, then I made a function that takes the file and vector as parameters, and populates the vector with `student` objects.

```cpp
void getStudents(std::fstream& file, std::vector< Student >& list)
{
    char userType;
    std::string user, pswd;
    file.seekg(0, file.beg);

    Student newStudent;
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        file >> newStudent;
        list.push_back(newStudent);
    }
}
```

I also overloaded the `>>` operator to print the `student` class to `cout`:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& output, Student& student)
{
    output << "Username: " << student.getUsername() << std::endl << "Password: ";
    output << student.getPassword() << std::endl;
    return output;
}
```

Finally, I wrote this in `main()` to test if it is all working:

```cpp
vector<Student> students;
fstream studentFile("Student.txt", ios::in);

cout << "Students:\n\n";
getStudents(studentFile, students);

for (int i = 0; i < (int)students.size(); i++)
{
    cout << students[i];
}
```

But, when I run it, it outputs:

```
Students:

Username:
Password:
Username: HaHa
Password: 7012
Username: HaHa
Password: 7012
Teachers:
```

I'm not really sure how to fix it. Everything worked fine when I read from `cin` instead of the `student.txt` file.

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: ^ That's part of the issue, the other would be that your operator can produce an invalid (?) `Student`, but you never check if that happened when reading file, before pushing such invalid Student into the vector.

Comment: i changed it so that it checks if it is a valid student object which fixed the empty fields, but it is still creating duplicate students in the vector.

Comment: @corl Fixing the broken `while` loop should avoid the issue with invalid students in the vector. Change `while (!file.eof()) { file >> newStudent; list.push_back(newStudent); }` to `while (file >> newStudent) { list.push_back(newStudent); }`